# NDSolve Euler-Lagrange equation encounter indeterminate expressions 0

Tags: differential-equations

I want to find the extremals of `Integrate[Sqrt[g'[x]^2+Sin[g[x]]^2], {x, 0.5, T}]`, The condition that must be met is `g[0.5]==0` and `g[T]=2*pi`, but no limit of T.

The corresponding Euler-Lagrange equation is `Sin[g[x]] (Cos[g[x]] (Sin[g[x]]^2 + 2 g'[x]^2) - Sin[g[x]] g''[x]) == 0`

therefore I try to plot the trajectories 'g[x]' in "{x,0.5,2.5}" by

```
   Plot[NDSolveValue[{Sin[g[x]] (Cos[g[x]] (Sin[g[x]]^2 + 2 g'[x]^2) - Sin[g[x]] g''[x]) == 0, g[0.5] == 0, g'[0.5] == 0}, g, {x, 0.5, 2.5}][t], {t, 0.5, 2.5}]
```

but encounter indeterminate expressions 0 at x==0.5.

why can’t the initial condition `g[0.5]==0,g'[0.5]==0` make the equation equals to 0?

what can I do to solve the E-L eq under the initial constraint?

Comment: Your code is riddled with mistakes: typos and missing parentheses. Please correct them so that the code runs and generates the error you describe.

Comment: @Roman  So sorry about my carelessness. Now it has been edited.

Comment: Can you work with small but non-zero values for g[0.5] and g'[0.5]? For example, if I use 1^-20 for both, I get a solution with no trouble. Since you're dealing with machine precision quantities, you only get roughly 16 digits of precision anyway. Plugging exactly 0 in probably is causing terms in your equation to drop out, leading to your problems.

Comment: hi @jdp, g[0.5] must be 0, and I tried g[0.5]=10^-20 following your advise but the same problem ocuresed.

Comment: Did you do both g and g'? I was able to run it a moment ago and generated a plot without any errors. Plot[NDSolveValue[{Sin[
       g[x]] (Cos[g[x]] (Sin[g[x]]^2 + 2 g'[x]^2) - 
        Sin[g[x]] g''[x]) == 0, g[0.5] == 1^-20, g'[0.5] == 1^-20}, 
   g, {x, 0.5, 2.5}][t], {t, 0.5, 2.5}]. What's the reason it "must" be 0 versus being very close? It is, after all, a numerical solution and has a certain degree of imprecision anyway; shifting the initial/boundary conditions is a common way to deal with problems like this.

Comment: thank you @jdp! Using 10^-20 for both g[0.5] & g'[0.5] works. Very close to 0 could satisfy my requirement. Then I try to solve my Non-showcased problem:    Plot[NDSolveValue[{g''[x] == 
     2 g'[x]^2 Cot[g[x]] + 
      Sin[g[x]] Cos[
        g[x]] + ((-2.21305)*Sin[x] - (-0.84521)*Cos[x])*(g'[x]^2 + 
         Sin[g[x]]^2)^(3/2), g[1.43*\[Pi]] == \[Pi]/3, 
    g[\[Pi]/2] == 0}, g, {x, \[Pi]/2, 1.43*\[Pi]}][t], {t, \[Pi]/
  2, 1.43*\[Pi]}] with the condition g[\[pi]/2]=0. It is solvable when g[\[pi]/2] is greater than 10^-6. I'm wondering if the precision can be larger.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Yes, you can increase precision. Right now, you are working with machine precision, which uses and is limited by the hardware on your computer. It's very fast, but you generally get 64/128 bits of precision. Look at the tutorial on "arbitrary precisioin": tutorial/Numbers#4686 in the documentation center. You can also set options like AccuracyGoal/PrecisionGoal/WorkingPrecision for NDSolve and related functions.

Comment: @jdp Thanks again for your kind answer. I'll take a hard look at the tutorial you suggest.

Comment: It's also possible to enter arbitrary precision numbers directly. For example, if I want to enter 1^-20 to (roughly) 30 digits of arbitrary precision, I can use 1.0`30^-20. If you run Precision[%] on the output, you get 28.699. The backtick is used to specify precision. A double backtick controls accuracy as well, and I believe they can be combined. I.e. 1.0`30`20^-20 etc. This is also in the documentation somewhere, though I can't recall where at the moment.

Comment: Your first expression (the one you're trying to find the extremals of) is still buggy. Is it `Integrate[Sqrt[g'[x]^2]+Sin[g[x]]^2, {x, 0.5, T}]` or `Integrate[Sqrt[g'[x]^2+Sin[g[x]]^2], {x, 0.5, T}]`?

Comment: @Roman It is the last one. Thanks for your correction.

Comment: @jdp That's a nice way to do it, I'll use it.